# I need an Adobe AIR developpement tools in html+javascript

Tags: sdk, air, adobe

I have been request to build AIR application. If i understand correctly, air apps can be "done" in flash or HTML+JavaScript. I don't like flash, and don't what to do flash, so what software SDK kit i can use to "make" HTML+JavaScript AIR apps, on pc or Mac ?

I have read about Flex, but seem to me that it's a flash dev tool ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to use HTML+JS for AIR apps. I'm not sure what OS you use, so I can recommend giving [Aptana with the AIR plugin](http://www.aptana.com/products/air/) a go since it's based on eclipse and should run on multiple operating systems.

I presume there might be other IDEs and editors with bundles that support AIR development, but haven't used them myself.Looking forward to see what other options are out there.

Comment: I develop on macintosh, and i dont know how to "compile" IR apps written in html+JS (now)

Comment: Aptana should take care of that for you: once you've defined an air html project it would only be a matter of pressing the Run button. Check out [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Cf2PXoBSiA) for example. Also, it should be possible to use Dreamweaver (version CS4 or newer) for HTML/JS AIR project. Again, googling for [tutorials](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/6/26/Working-with-Adobe-AIR-and-Dreamweaver-CS-55) will help.